# <HTML> download .sql file

Tags: javascript, html, file, download

I'm working on a **Angular** App

I've this function

`

```
vm.DownloadFile = function (item) {


                var a = document.createElement('A');
                a.href = item.fileSourceUrl;

                a.download = item.fileSourceUrl.substr(item.fileSourceUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                document.body.appendChild(a);

                a.click();
                document.body.removeChild(a);


    }
```

`

This allows me to download files from my view using an url .
It works fine, i can download my files with that.

The problem I just noticed is that i can't download .sql files . Why ? 
Many types of file are working , `.jpg` , `.pdf` , `.dwf` ... everything but `.sql`

Comment: what is happening for `.sql` is it opening in another tab / same tab?

Comment: Failed - File not found. 
The download footer appears ( in chrome ) but i get " Failed - File not found."
If i try to reach the file typing the file's url i can have a 404 error, this is not happening with other files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong , MIME type for .sql was not set in my IIS configuration.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to set MIME type for .sql files**

To set MIME type

Open IIS Manager

In Features View, double-click MIME Types.

In the Actions pane, click Add.

In the Add MIME Type dialog box, type a file name extension in the File name extension text box.

Type a MIME type in the MIME type text box.

Click OK.